# Does "No such device"->grub rescue on on an established system herald a catastrophic event?

Tags: hard-drive, grubrescue

I've already found plenty of threads on "no such device" and grub rescue on AskUbuntu, but I'm wondering what this signifies if it happens not on a fresh install, but on a computer that has been behaving normally for well over a year.

Is this a sign of catastrophic hard drive failure, or possibly another issue? Or is it a just-happens kind of thing that crops up from time to time with Ubuntu?

Comment: Did you updated the system before the problem happen? If you boot from a Live Edition do you see the HDD?

Comment: No, it happened after a reboot of the system (which was running normally). Trying to track down my Live CD so I can see what's what, but the HDDs are all visible from BIOS.

Comment: The Boot Repair Disk seems to have fixed things for the moment, but I'm still quite nervous about what this means...

Comment: Don't worry, it could happen some times. Check the *disk* utility to know your HDD status. Don't forget to create a new answer telling how did you solved it!

Comment: @guntbert I don't think so. Anyway, it would be preferable to mark it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I repair grub? (How to get Ubuntu back after installing Windows?)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows)

Comment: @guntbert You're right. This is not a duplicate. (Probably not of anything.) It's asking about the *causes* of this problem, not the *solutions*. Sorry I thought otherwise.